# convert jquery object to string

Tags: php, jquery, html

This is my object array

```
 [Object { qe="1-5",  result="0"}, Object { qe="1-5",  result="1"}, Object { qe="8+9",  result="0"}]
```

and I need to send this array as a href link

something like this :

index.php?mode=result&link= OBJECT

Now I need to know how to convert this specific type of array into string

I have a demo here but not useful:

http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/bchG5/

Comment: I find it funny that you link to a fiddle I created two years ago ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you can just send it as a JSON string.  You can use `JSON.stringify` on the object:

```
encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(value));
```

On the php side, `json_decode($_REQUEST['link'])` will convert it into usable PHP constructs (arrays, objects).

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
var obj= [Object { qe="1-5",  result="0"}, Object { qe="1-5",  result="1"}, Object { qe="8+9",  result="0"}]
alert(JSON.stringify(obj));
```